# Exportação query para EXCEL em PHP erro UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8

Quando faço a exportação dos dados o UTF-8 não está agindo, como posso resolver isto?

```
// Formatação do header do arquivo
header ("Expires: Mon, 18 Nov 1985 18:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s")." GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Dados.xls");

header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";

?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fazenda</th>
            <th>Talhão</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Deficit (mm)</th>
            <th>Irrigação (mm)</th>
            <th>Irrigação (h)</th>
            <th>Velocidade (%)</th>
            <th>Pluviometria (mm)</th>
            <th>Temp Min (°C)</th>
            <th>Temp Med (°C)</th>
            <th>Temp Max (°C)</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php
            while ($Dado = $conexao->busca($Dados))
            {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$Dado['Nome_Fazenda']?></td>
                    <td><?=$Dado['Nome_Parcela']?></td>
                    <td><?=$Dado['Data_Irr']?></td>
                    <td><?=$Dado['Deficit']?></td>
                    <td><?=$Dado['IrrMM']?></td>
                    <td><?=$Dado['IrrHS']?></td>
                    <td><?=$Dado['Velocidade']?></td>
                    <td><?=$Dado['Pluviometria']?></td>
                    <td><?=$Dado['Temp_Min']?></td>
                    <td><?=$Dado['Temp_Med']?></td>
                    <td><?=$Dado['Temp_Max']?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
```

[image: Planilha]

Comment: o problema ocorre nos elementos que vêm do bd ou todos, incluindo os que vc digitou à mão?

Comment: em todo, vou colocar uma imagem para você ver como fica, ainda vem um símbolo no começo.

Comment: @WeesSmith fiz a alteração.

Comment: tem algo antes desses headers?

Comment: Sim, uma query para buscar na variável $dados.

Comment: os headers tem que serem os primeiros de tudo, coloca eles isolados no topo da pagina logo abaixo do <?php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os `header()`s devem vir sempre no topo da página, antes de qualquer coisa:

```
<?php
    header ("Expires: Mon, 18 Nov 1985 18:00:00 GMT");
    header ("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s")." GMT");
    header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header ("Pragma: no-cache");
    header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Dados.xls");
    header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração, mesmo assim não deu certo.

Comment: deixa só o `header("charset=UTF-8")` e tira os outros para ver

Comment: Na página aparece tudo certo, quando está exportando para o Excel que não está dando certo

Comment: da uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164719/utf-8-encoding-xml-in-php

Comment: Beleza, vou verificar.

Comment: Consegui amigo, obrigado!